# Highchart blinking when using multiple dynamic chart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I've created a common chart component in Angular so I can send data from a parent component and get the desired chart rendered.

The chart data gets generated dynamically after I receive data from a few http requests, I am using multiple instances of the chart component.

The issue - Lets say I am trying to render three charts, I do three api calls a, b, c. Once I get data from "a" the first chart gets rendered and if I get data from "b" later then a blinks once, then again if I get the data from "c" then the first chart and the second chart blinks twice or thrice.

How can I get rid of the Blinking when rendering the rest of the charts. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to combine all three API calls, so that the data only gets sent once to the child component. This should help with the blinking. You could try something like `combineLatest` if you are working with Observables, or `Promise.all()` with Promises.

Comment: Try to render all your charts after getting the API call when data will be fetched and ready to use. In case of any trouble, please reproduce your case on some online editor.

Comment: I am currently doing the same thing but a few endpoints take time to respond due to which there's a long wait before data can be presented, I'm trying to avoid that